# Return which condition terminated a loop

Tags: java, loops, conditional-statements

Say I have the following while loop:

```
int var1 = 3, var2 = 1;
while (var1 != 0 && var2 != var1) {
    var1--;
}
```

What would be the most elegant way to know which condition caused the loop to end?

Comment: "What would be the most elegant way to know which condition caused the loop to end?". well since you're using logical "or" the loop will terminate if both are false, so there is your answer.

Comment: I messed up, meant while **both conditions** were true

Comment: Any. What I woud like is a way to have the while loop tell me which conditions was not met.

Comment: FYI, I updated my answer after you accepted it. `result2` doesn't really help you...

Comment: Yes, I understood what you meant; `&` evaluates both conditions, `&&` doesn't. I was already doing #2, just wondered if there was a "built-in" way where while "tells you" what condition was not met instead of you needing to track them with booleans.

Comment: @CaffeinatedSynapse: Nope. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your choices are basically:

1. Check again afterward, or
2. Save the information to variables.

Here's #2:

```
int var1 = 3;
int var2 = 1;
boolean result1;
boolean result2 = false;
while ((result1 = var1 != 0) && (result2 = var2 != var1)) {
    var1--;
}
```

**Note** that you need a default value on `result2` (you could use `true` if you prefer, whatever makes sense in the code) because `&&` short-circuits, which means that if the first operand isn't true, the second is never evaluated, and the compiler would complain that `result2` may not have been initialized.

Actually, you only need `result1` (since `result2` won't be updated if `result1` is `false`, so it doesn't really tell you anything; if `result1` is `false`, `result2`'s value will be from the *previous* loop [or the default]). You'd probably be better off doing this:

```
int var1 = 3;
int var2 = 1;
boolean result1;
while ((result1 = var1 != 0) && var2 != var1) {
    var1--;
}
if (result1) {
    // It was the "var2 != var1" condition that ended the loop
} else {
    // It was the "va1 != 0" condition that ended the loop
}
```

If you want to always evaluate both options for some reason, as [Bubletan points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874291/return-which-condition-terminated-a-loop/42874419#comment72853161_42874419), you can use `&`, which (with booleans) is just like `&&` except it doesn't short-circuit:

```
int var1 = 3;
int var2 = 1;
boolean result1;
boolean result2;
while ((result1 = var1 != 0) & (result2 = var2 != var1)) {
    var1--;
}
```

Comment: Another way is using `&` instead of `&&`.